# Microsoft Teams breakout room api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've been unable to find out whether it's possible to create breakout rooms programmatically for Microsoft Teams -- and assign the participants to the breakout rooms via API. Is that possible? Can somebody please point me to the appropriate documentation?

Comment: Breakout rooms: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-breakout-rooms-in-teams-meetings-7de1f48a-da07-466c-a5ab-4ebace28e461

Comment: The team is working on it, as of now I don't have an ETA to share.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as of now to create Breakout Rooms with any API. It's in the backlog and team is working. As of now we don't have an ETA to share.

You can refer to this as shared by @Konard -
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-breakout-rooms-in-teams-meetings-7de1f48a-da07-466c-a5ab-4ebace28e461

Answer (score 1):

It's still not possible.

You can also refer to Microsoft Graph REST API (beta).
Recently Microsoft added new APIs for "Cloud Communications/Meetings", however breakout support is not provided.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta